# Подскажите пожалуйста как сдвинуть текстовый элемент влево в картинке?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю как  сдвинуть указанный элемент влево, margin-right не работает.

```
.staging__firts-text-bottom{
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 8px;
        left: 16px;
        font-family: Open Sans Condensed;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 25px;
        letter-spacing: 0.1em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        margin-bottom: 110px;
        margin-top: 300px;
        white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: А как насчет left: 0px; в css?

Answer (score 0):

display: flex;
justify-content: flex-start;

Comment: Пострайтесь писать чуть более развёрнутые ответы.